# Is there an explanation for why the Vong were not included in the rebooted Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars

When the Clone Wars series was relaunched several years ago, I was highly anticipating that Dave Filoni and Pablo Hidalgo might reuse some of [what they had been working on](https://www.starwars.com/news/swca-the-untold-clone-wars-panel-liveblog) before they stopped working on the series.

Specifically, why there has not been an attempt to revive the Yuuzhan Vong? I remember that there was a plan to make [an X-Files style episode which featured the Vong](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong#The_Clone_Wars).

Is there any official response from Dave Filoni, Pablo Hidalgo, or anyone else at LucasFilm, on why the Vong were not revisited?

Comment: What does SWCA stand for?

Comment: whoops, mistype

Comment: specifics would be helpful - since the last season (recently released on Disney+) *did* salvage old material they didn't get to finish

Comment: @NKCampbell adjusted appropriately

Comment: I'm struggling to find a reliable source for the "X-Files-esque episode" claim. Presumably Filoni mentioned this at a panel at some convention, but it's not mentioned in the live blog you linked, although the claim is [repeated by Gizmodo here](https://io9.gizmodo.com/everything-we-know-about-the-untold-stories-of-the-clon-1827908786).

Comment: as much as the various Thrawn storylines in new canon keep positing a threat in the Unknown Regions, it's certainly possible they are holding the Borg...I mean Vong, back for that. Or perhaps the new High Republic series.

Comment: also - it might have been a licensing / $$$ thing to include the Vong. Zahn obviously was involved in bringing Thrawn into the new Disney landscape, but it's uncertain who exactly owns the idea of the Vong. Similar to how in Star Trek, Tom Paris was originally going to be Nick Locarno in Voyager, but they didn't want to pay the original writers of the script that introduced Locarno. Similar things may be in play there.

Comment: Maybe including them would have been the right thing to do, but for the Vong reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Keep in mind though, the Vong in TCW was just an idea they were tossing around and never got past the conceptual stage, so it's not like they had a complete story and script ready to go.
It's a fair bet that had Filoni *really* wanted to tell a version of that story it would have ended up in 'Rebels'. Someone may pick up that idea somewhere down the line if they feel it's a story they want to tell, and maybe not.
That said, they've already brought back the likes of Jaxxon the green space rabbit, so it's probably just a matter of time before some new incarnation of the Vong show up. Preferably a less boring one...

Answer (score 1):

### Speculation: The idea was dropped because the Expanded Universe was decanonized

Any planning that the showrunners for *The Clone Wars* did before its cancellation would have had to have happened in 2013 or earlier. This may have been before Disney bought Star Wars in 2012, and would definitely have been before Disney announced that Legends (the former Expanded Universe) was no longer canon in 2014. This means at the time they were considering this, the Yuuzhan Vong would still have been considered Star Wars canon.

By the time the final season was produced, the Expanded Universe had been scrapped and the Yuuzhan Vong no longer had any appearances in canon. Since the main significance of the Yuuzhan Vong was their role in the Legends *New Jedi Order* novel series, an episode that served to set them up would likely be confusing to audiences if it came out after the novels were no longer canon.